# Vue blocks script reference

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I have a general Q. I cannot load scripts inside my vue div which encompasses everything in between body in my laravel app. My custom js files only work if I import them globally below the div id="app". What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav></nav>
        @yield('content') // when vue is loaded, scripts don't work on their respective files. Error message on console is removed with vue.min.js but the error persists
    </div>
// when vue is loaded, scripts only work if referenced globally here
```

I am importing vue via
https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js

Comment: Give us more information please.

Comment: When I import vue from CDN and create a wrapper <div id="#app> below and above my opening & closing body tags, any custom JS scripts that I have created don't get referenced when vue is implemented. I need to move them outside of the @yeild('content') </div> // closing vue app instance i.e. import them globally for them to work. Remove vue and they work as expected in their respective html files

Comment: Do you get any error or warning on the console?

Comment: Yes. I have vue loader configured with webpack now so this error is closed for me but if you are referencing vue2 from cdn and you have custom javascript files referenced below closing divs in-between blade templates on laravel @extends('layouts.app', @section('content') // html // custom js @stop, the js files here will throw an error and not work. This error is not visible with vue.min.js but the files will not work unless they are moved outside of the vue div reference and you may need to reorder them to get them to work as expected